# QJSValue call Array.prototype.push not working

Tags: c++, qt, qjsengine

I want to evaluate my JS array through QJSValue and call required methods. For example: `push`, `splice`, etc... But calling `Array.prototype.push` (or others) has no effect.

```cpp
//QQmlApplicationEngine myEngine;
auto arr = myEngine->evaluate("[1, 2, 3]");
qDebug() << arr.isArray(); //true
qDebug() << arr.property("length").toInt(); //3
qDebug() << arr.property("push").call({4, 5, 6}); //call Array.prototype.push
qDebug() << arr.property("length").toInt(); //3
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `qDebug() << arr.property("push").call({4, 5, 6}).toInt();` - what dose this return?

Comment: qDebug() << arr.property("push").call({4, 5, 6}).toVariant(); // QVariant(int, 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
arr.property("push").call({4, 5, 6});
```

looks like to be JS with `this` set to the `Array` instance:

```js
Array.protoype.push(4, 5, 6);
```

Try to call the property with `this` set to the `arr` instance:

```
arr.property("push").callWithInstance(arr, {4, 5, 6});
```